# Get Text From Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have code to read data from Access Database

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Public Class Form2
        Dim CMD As OleDbConnection
        Dim RD As OleDbDataReader
        Dim Go As OleDbCommand
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim a As Integer = 0
        Dim r As Integer = 0
    Private Sub BT1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BT1.Click
            If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
                Call Connect()
                Go = New OleDbCommand("select * from Account where ID='" & TxtID.Text & "' and Password='" & TxtPw.Text & "'", Conn)
                RD = Go.ExecuteReader
                If RD.Read Then
                    Menu1.Show()
                    Form1.Hide()
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("ID or Password is Incorrect!", "InCorrect", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End If
            Else

            End If
        End Sub
```

and my table look is here

```
ID      Password Name  
------- -------- ----
User001 User001  Van
```

when the button is clicked, then show Messagebox with text, Name from Table

The Question is, how to get Name Record from my Table ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly you are looking for this:

```
dim positionInResult as Integer = Rd.GetOrdinal("Name")
dim name as String = Rd.GetString(positionInResult)
```

This assumes that you do not know how to get the "Name" value out of the DataReader

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.